# Нужен ли здесь предлог?

Tags: общие-вопросы, предлоги

Как правильно: орган Контроля над автомобильным траспортом или орган Контроля автотраспорта? Речь идет об огране в Болгарии, подобному российскому ГИБДД.

Answer (score 4):

Из ответа справки [Грамоты.ру](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_161)

Слово контроль употребляется со следующими предлогами:

1. контроль **за чем и над чем** - при отглагольных существительных, то есть образованных от глаголов: контроль за / над расходованием средств (расходование от расходовать); контроль за исполнением приказа (исполнение от исполнить);
2. контроль **за чем** - при существительных, обозначающих действие или признак: контроль за работой станка (действие); контроль за качеством работы (признак); контроль за монтажом (действие); контроль за окружающей средой (качество; наблюдение за состоянием и изменением особо важных для человека и биоты характеристик компонентов ландшафта); контроль за отгрузкой (действие); контроль за производством (= процессом) тары.
3. контроль **над кем-чем** - при существительных отвлеченных и при одушевленных существительных: контроль над производством (= организация); контроль над молодыми специалистами (одушевленные сущ.);
4. контроль **чего** - в официальной и профессионально-технической речи: контроль деятельности выборных органов; контроль готовой продукции; контроль коммерческих условий.

Соответственно в вашем случае случае можно использовать предлог **за**, так как здесь автотранспорт используется в значении качественные изменения в автомобильном потоке, влияющие на дорожное движение (2). Вполне допустимо и обойтись без предлога вообще (4).

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за подробный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Варианты  "контроль над" и "контроль за" равнодопустимы. В научной литературе встречается и "контроль (чего?)", который тоже считается нормативным.

В Вашем случае первый из двух предложенных вариантов подходит больше, поскольку речь не идет о научно-технической сфере. 
Но лучше всего, пожалуй, будет **"контроль за"**, поскольку в данном случае выглядит нейтральнее ("контроль над" предполагает, скорее, "вертикальную" структуру).

Что касается цитированного ответа "Справки" то при всей его правильности, он не очень конкретен, обо не учитывает конкретику. В результате при общем правильном выводе, причины его названы неточно.

Но, в принципе, повторюсь, допустимы все три варианта.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный и вразумительный ответ. Вопрос возник в связи с редакцией перевода с болгарского языка. Редактор поправил на второй вариант: орган Контроля автотраспорта. Показалось сомнительно.

Answer (score 0):

В деловых бумагах принято писать: "Органы, осуществляющие функции по контролю и надзору в сфере транспорта"или"органы контроля за соблюдением законов, иных нормативных актов по вопросам безопасности дорожного движения".

А может, "орган контроля в автомобильном транспорте"(т.е. в отрасли нар. хозяйства)?

Comment: Речь идет о расшифровке аббревиатуры КАТ (Контроль (за) (над) автотранспортом). Орган КАТ в Болгарии все равно, что ГИБДД в России. Длинная формулировка просто никак не подходит.